# Moving a jQuery draggable() element to a new parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, parent-child, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm writing a simple card game in JavaScript, and I'd like to have a "card" `img` snap to its target when played.  I'm accomplishing this by removing the `img` from its current parent and placing it in a new parent (the target).  However, when I place the `img` in its new container with jQuery's `.appendTo()`, the card snaps to the corner of the screen.

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NathanFriend/hsjvP/) for a working example.

Is there a reason the `div` snaps to the corner of the screen when it's moved to a new parent?  I'm wondering if there are css properties that are being inherited/lost behind the scenes when I change the `div`'s parent.

Any help would be appreciated.

**- EDIT -**

Additional information: while it has been suggested that I simply add this to my drop handler (which works) -

`$(ui.draggable).css({'top' : '0', 'left' : '0'});`

I'd like to `.animate()` to this position, so the snap isn't instantaneous.  While the card does end up in the correct spot, it first snaps to the corner and then eases into the correct position.  I'd like to avoid that first snap to the corner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(ui.draggable).css({'top' : '0', 'left' : '0'});
```

Sorry, I had to leave for work, but try this:

```
$("#target").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
      var offset = $('#target').offset()
      var top = parseInt($(ui.draggable).css('top')) - offset.top;
      var left = parseInt($(ui.draggable).css('left')) - offset.left;            
      $(ui.draggable).appendTo("#target");
      $(ui.draggable).css({'top' : top, 'left' : left})
      $(ui.draggable).animate({
        top: 0,
        left: 0           
      }, 500, function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsjvP/22/

Comment: Thanks for the comment - this is a perfect solution for how my question was first phrased.  Unfortunately, it's a little more complex - see my edit.